# Decompression of a list in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, predicate

I need to decompress a list in prolog , like in the example below :

```
decode([[a,1],[b,2],[c,1],[d,3]],L). 
L = [a, b, b, c, d, d, d] ;
```

I made this code :

```
divide(L,X,Y):-length(X,1),append(X,Y,L).

divide2(L,X,Y):-divide(L,[X|_],[Y|_]).


makelist(_,N,[]):- N =< 0 .
makelist(X,Y,[X|Result]):-Y1 is Y-1,makelist(X,Y1,Result).

makelist2(L,L2):-divide2(L,X,Y),makelist(X,Y,L2).

decode([],[]).
decode([H|T],L):-makelist2(H,H2),append(H2,L,L2),decode(T,L2).
```

and when i call

```
makelist2([a,3],L2).
L2 = [a,a,a].
```

but when i call

`decode([[a,3],[b,1],[c,4]],L)`

runs continuously. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I provided an additional answer to help explain the issues in your code in more detail.

Comment: There are a number of answers provided. Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another variation of the theme, using a slightly modified version of Boris' `repeat/3` predicate:

```
% True when L is a list with N repeats of X
repeat([X, N], L) :-
    length(L, N),
    maplist(=(X), L).

decode(Encoded, Decoded) :-
    maplist(repeat, Encoded, Expanded),
    flatten(Expanded, Decoded).
```

If `Encode = [[a,1],[b,2],[c,1],[d,3]]`, then in the above `decode/2`, the `maplist/3` call will yield `Expanded = [[a],[b,b],[c],[d,d,d]]`, and then the `flatten/2` call results in `Decoded = [a,b,b,c,d,d,d]`.

In SWI Prolog, instead of `flatten/2`, you can use `append/2` since you only need a "flattening" at one level.

---

**EDIT**: Adding a "bidirectional" version, using a little CLPFD:

```
rle([], []).
rle([X], [[1,X]]).
rle([X,Y|T], [[1,X]|R]) :-
    X \== Y,     % use dif(X, Y) here, if available
    rle([Y|T], R).
rle([X,X|T], [[N,X]|R]) :-
    N #= N1 + 1,
    rle([X|T], [[N1,X]|R]).
```

This will yield:

```
| ?- rle([a,a,a,b,b], L).

L = [[3,a],[2,b]] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?- rle(L, [[3,a],[2,b]]).

L = [a,a,a,b,b] ? ;

no
| ?- rle([a,a,a,Y,Y,Z], [X, [N,b],[M,c]]).

M = 1
N = 2
X = [3,a]
Y = b
Z = c ? a

no
| ?- rle([A,B,C], D).

D = [[1,A],[1,B],[1,C]] ? ;

C = B
D = [[1,A],[2,B]] ? ;

B = A
D = [[2,A],[1,C]] ? ;

B = A
C = A
D = [[3,A]] ? ;

(2 ms) no
| ?- rle(A, [B,C]).

A = [D,E]
B = [1,D]
C = [1,E] ? ;

A = [D,E,E]
B = [1,D]
C = [2,E] ? ;

A = [D,E,E,E]
B = [1,D]
C = [3,E] ? ;
...

| ?- rle(A, B).

A = []
B = [] ? ;

A = [C]
B = [[1,C]] ? ;

A = [C,D]
B = [[1,C],[1,D]] ? ;
...
```

As @mat suggests in his comment, in Prolog implementations that have `dif/2`, then `dif(X,Y)` is preferable to `X \== Y` above.

Comment: A very good solution. I just have a pathological dislike for `flatten` :) but in this case it allows for a clean solution.

Comment: quoting from [the docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2), "Ending up needing flatten/3 often indicates ... a bad design.", but you don't actually need `flatten/2`, only `flatten_one_level/2`, better known as [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:concat) in the FP world. Which is perfectly fine and dandy.

Comment: @WillNess right. I'm used to doing things through GNU Prolog. In SWI I could use `append/2`.

Comment: +1 for attempting an omnidirectional solution. In SICStus Prolog, SWI and several others, you can use `dif/2` instead of `(\==)/2` to make it correct.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the order of your `append` and `decode` in the last clause of `decode`. Try tracing it, or even better, trace it "by hand" to see what happens.

Another approach: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310855/check-if-a-list-is-made-up-of-n-instances-of-x-repeat-x-n-times/27311574#27311574). So, with `repeat/3` defined as:

```
% True when L is a list with N repeats of X
repeat(X, N, L) :-
    length(L, N),
    maplist(=(X), L).
```

You can write your `decode/2` as:

```
decode([], []).
decode([[X,N]|XNs], Decoded) :-
    decode(XNs, Decoded_rest),
    repeat(X, N, L),
    append(L, Decoded_rest, Decoded).
```

But this is a slightly roundabout way to do it. You could define a difference-list version of `repeat/3`, called say `repeat/4`:

```
repeat(X, N, Reps, Reps_back) :-
    (   succ(N0, N)
    ->  Reps = [X|Reps0],
        repeat(X, N0, Reps0, Reps_back)
    ;   Reps = Reps_back
    ).
```

And then you can use a difference-list version of `decode/2`, `decode_1/3`

```
decode(Encoded, Decoded) :-
    decode_1(Encoded, Decoded, []).

decode_1([], Decoded, Decoded).
decode_1([[X,N]|XNs], Decoded, Decoded_back) :-
    repeat(X, N, Decoded, Decoded_rest),
    decode_1(XNs, Decoded_rest, Decoded_back).


?- decode([[a,1],[b,2],[c,1],[d,3]],L).
L = [a, b, b, c, d, d, d].

?- decode([[a,3],[b,1],[c,0],[d,3]],L).
L = [a, a, a, b, d, d, d].

?- decode([[a,3]],L).
L = [a, a, a].

?- decode([],L).
L = [].
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i tested,it works but i am very new in prolog , this code being over my power of understanding the language . May i have a little bit help in understanding what i'm doing wrong in my example ?

Comment: @MoroianuAlexandru See the first paragraph of my answer

Comment: @MoroianuAlexandru and note that both my first solution and the very nice solution by @capellic do the `append` only after making a proper list, not before that.

Answer (score 2):

You can deal with both direction with this code :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
% code from Pascal Bourguignon
packRuns([],[]).

packRuns([X],[[X]]).

packRuns([X|Rest],[XRun|Packed]):-
    run(X,Rest,XRun,RRest),
    packRuns(RRest,Packed).


run(Var,[],[Var],[]).

run(Var,[Var|LRest],[Var|VRest],RRest):-
    run(Var,LRest,VRest,RRest).

run(Var,[Other|RRest],[Var],[Other|RRest]):-
    dif(Var,Other).
%end code

pack_1(In, Out) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(X = [V|_],
              Y = [V, N],
              length(X, N),
              maplist(=(V), X)),
        In, Out).

decode(In, Out) :-
    when((ground(In); ground(Out1)),pack_1(Out1, In)),
    packRuns(Out, Out1).
```

Output :

```
 ?- decode([[a,1],[b,2],[c,1],[d,3]],L).

L = [a, b, b, c, d, d, d] .

 ?- decode(L, [a,b,b,c,d,d,d]).

L = [[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 1], [d, 3]] .
```

Comment: Nice shot at a relational solution (+1). Although, `decode([[a,1],[c,0],[b,3]], L).` fails. But for a relational solution, perhaps expecting the counts to be `> 0` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

a compact way:

```
decode(L,D) :- foldl(expand,L,[],D).
expand([S,N],L,E) :- findall(S,between(1,N,_),T), append(L,T,E).
```

findall/3 it's the 'old fashioned' Prolog list comprehension facility

Comment: Great answer as always. I am not sure, but can you use the four-argument `findall/4` to avoid the `append` in `expand/3` completely?

Comment: @Boris: actually, I tried, but it gives the reversed answer: `expand([S,N],L,E) :- findall(S,between(1,N,_),E,L).`

Answer (score 1):

`decode` is a poor name for your predicate: properly done, you predicate should be bi-directional — if you say

```
decode( [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]] , L )
```

You should get

```
L = [a,b,b,c,c,c].
```

And if you say

```
decode( L , [a,b,b,c,c,c] ) .
```

You should get

```
L = [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]].
```

So I'd use a different name, something like `run_length_encoding/2`. I might also not use a list to represent individual run lengths as `[a,1]` is this prolog term: `.(a,.(1,[])`. Just use a simple term with arity 2 — myself, I like using `:/2` since it's defined as an infix operator, so you can simply say `a:1`.

Try this on for size:

```
run_length_encoding( []     , []     ) .  % the run-length encoding of the empty list is the empty list.
run_length_encoding( [X|Xs] , [R|Rs] ) :- % the run-length encoding of a non-empty list is computed by
  rle( Xs , X:1 , T , R ) ,               % - run-length encoding the prefix of the list
  run_length_encoding( T , Rs )           % - and recursively run-length encoding the remainder
  .                                       % Easy!

rle( []     , C:N , []     , C:N ) .  % - the run is complete when the list is exhausted.
rle( [X|Xs] , C:N , [X|Xs] , C:N ) :- % - the run is complete,
  X \= C                              % - when we encounter a break
  .                                   %
rle( [X|Xs] , X:N , T      , R   ) :- % - the run continues if we haven't seen a break, so....
  N1 is N+1 ,                         % - increment the run length,
  rle( Xs, X:N1, T, R )               % - and recurse down.
  .                                   % Easy!
```

Comment: `run_length_encoding([a,b,b,c,c,c], L).` yields `L = [a:1,b:2,c:3]`, but `run_length_encoding(L, [a:1,b:2,c:3] ).` causes a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In direct answer to the original question of, *What am I doing wrong?*...

When I ran the original code, any expected use case "ran indefinitely" without yielding a result.

Reading through the main predicate:

```
decode([],[]).
```

This says that `[]` is the result of decoding `[]`. Sounds right.

```
decode([H|T],L) :- makelist2(H,H2), append(H2,L,L2), decode(T,L2).
```

This says that `L` is the result of decoding `[H|T]` if `H2` is an expansion of `H` (which is what `makelist2` does... perhaps - we'll go over that below), and `H2` appended to this result gives another list `L2` which is the decoded form of the original tail `T`. That doesn't sound correct. If I decode `[H|T]`, I should (1) expand `H`, (2) decode `T` giving `L2`, then (3) append `H` to `L2` giving `L`.

So the corrected second clause is:

```
decode([H|T], L) :- makelist2(H, H2), decode(T, L2), append(H2, L2, L).
```

Note the argument order of `append/3` and that the call occurs after the `decode` of the tail. As Boris pointed out previously, the incorrect order of `append` and the recursive `decode` can cause the continuous running without any output as `append` with more uninstantiated arguments generates a large number of unneeded possibilities before `decode` can succeed.

But now the result is:

```
| ?- decode([[a,3]], L).

L = [a,a,a] ? ;

L = [a,a,a,a] ? ;
...
```

If you try out our other predicates by hand in the Prolog interpreter, you'll find that `makelist2/2` has an issue:

It produces the correct result, but also a bunch of incorrect results. Let's have a look at `makelist2/2`. We can try this predicate by itself and see what happens:

```
| ?- makelist2([a,3], L).

L = [a,a,a] ? ;

L = [a,a,a,a] ? ;
...
```

There's an issue: `makelist2/2` should only give the first solution, but it keeps going, giving incorrect solutions. Let's look closer at `makelist/2`:

```
makelist2(L,L2) :- divide2(L,X,Y), makelist(X,Y,L2).
```

It takes a list `L` of the form `[A,N]`, divides it (via `divide2/3`) into `X = A` and `Y = N`, then calls an auxiliary, `makelist(X, Y, L2)`.

```
makelist(_,N,[]):- N =< 0 .
makelist(X,Y,[X|Result]):-Y1 is Y-1,makelist(X,Y1,Result).
```

`makelist/3` is supposed to generate a list (the third argument) by replicating the first argument the number of times given in the second argument. The second, recursive clause appears to be OK, but has one important flaw: it will succeed even if the value of `Y` is less than or equal to `0`. Therefore, even though a correct solution is found, it keeps succeeding on incorrect solutions because the base case allows the count to be `=< 0`:

```
| ?- makelist(a,2,L).

L = [a,a] ? ;

L = [a,a,a] ? ;
```

We can fix `makelist/2` as follows:

```
makelist(_,N,[]):- N =< 0 .
makelist(X,Y,[X|Result]):- Y > 0, Y1 is Y-1, makelist(X,Y1,Result).
```

Now the code will generate a correct result. We just needed to fix the second clause of `decode/2`, and the second clause of `makelist/3`.

```
| ?- decode([[a,3],[b,4]], L).

L = [a,a,a,b,b,b,b]

yes
```

The complete, original code with just these couple of corrections looks like this:

```
divide(L, X, Y) :- length(X, 1), append(X, Y, L).

divide2(L, X, Y) :- divide(L, [X|_], [Y|_]).

makelist(_, N, []) :- N =< 0 .
makelist(X, Y, [X|Result]) :- Y > 0, Y1 is Y-1, makelist(X,Y1,Result).

makelist2(L, L2) :- divide2(L, X, Y), makelist(X, Y, L2).

decode([], []).
decode([H|T], L) :- makelist2(H,H2), decode(T,L2), append(H2,L2,L).
```

Note some simple, direct improvements. The predicate, `divide2(L, X, Y)` takes a list `L` of two elements and yields each, individual element, `X` and `Y`. This predicate is unnecessary because, in Prolog, you can obtain these elements by simple unification: `L = [X, Y]`. You can try this right in the Prolog interpreter:

```
| ?- L = [a,3], L = [X,Y].

L = [a,3]
X = a
Y = 3

yes
```

We can then completely remove the `divide/3` and `divide2/3` predicates, and replace a call to `divide2(L, X, Y)` with `L = [X,Y]` and reduce `makelist2/2` to:

```
makelist2(L, L2) :- L = [X, Y], makelist(X, Y, L2).
```

Or more simply (because we can do the unification right in the head of the clause):

```
makelist2([X,Y], L2) :- makelist(X, Y, L2).
```

You could just remove `makelist2/2` and call `makelist/2` directly from `decode/2` by unifying `H` directly with its two elements, `[X, N]`. So the original code simplifies to:

```
makelist(_, N, []) :- N =< 0 .
makelist(X, Y, [X|Result]) :- Y > 0, Y1 is Y-1, makelist(X,Y1,Result).

decode([], []).
decode([[X,N]|T], L) :- makelist(X, N, H2), decode(T, L2), append(H2, L2, L).
```

And `makelist/3` can be performed a bit more clearly using one of the methods provided in the other answers (*e.g.*, see Boris' `repeat/3` predicate).